# Por que o meu PlayerPrefs (Unity) não funciona no Android?

Tags: javascript, android, datetime, unity3d

Essa é minha primeira pergunta e primeira postagem aqui!

Bom, estou fazendo um jogo no **Unity** **voltado para Android** e criei um **javascript** pra salvar e calcular alguns valores.

Funciona assim: Meu jogo possui alguns sliders que utilizo como status do meu personagem. Esses sliders **perdem pontos a cada segundo**, como um sistema de fome. Acontece que, se eu **fechasse** o jogo, o valor **resetava**. Então acabei descobrindo o **PlayerPrefs**. Fiz um javascript que, ao fechar o jogo, ele pegava a **data do sistema** (segundos, minutos ... meses e ano) e **guardava**. Ao abrir o jogo, ele **carregava esses dados**, transformava tudo em segundos, pegava a data atual do sistema e dava a diferença (também em segundos) de **quanto tempo o jogo ficou fechado.** Com base nisso, ele retira os pontos da barra que seriam perdidos caso o jogo estivesse aberto.

Tudo muito bem, funcionando no Unity bonitinho. Fecha, carrega, fecho Unity, abro, e ele continua funcionando certinho. Coloquei no celular... Nada. Desinstalei, instalei, limpei dados, e nada de funcionar.

O que eu estou fazendo errado? Tenho que configurar algo no Unity? Meu código esta errado?

Segue abaixo o javascript:

```
#pragma strict

//----------------------- Variaveis dos resultados -----------------------

//----------------------- Variaveis dos resultados -----------------------



//----------------------- Variaveis das Barras -----------------------

public var BarraFome : UnityEngine.UI.Slider;

public var BarraFelicidade : UnityEngine.UI.Slider;

public var BarraBanho : UnityEngine.UI.Slider;

public var BarraDormir : UnityEngine.UI.Slider;

//----------------------- Variaveis das Barras -----------------------






function Start(){


//-Pega o tempo atual

var dtnow : System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now;

//-Pega o tempo atual


//--------------------------- Calculo das diferenças dos tempos ---------------------------


//- Pega todos os tempos da ultima vez que abriu

var dtoldSec = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oldTimeSecond");
var dtoldMin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oldTimeMinute");
var dtoldHour = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oldTimeHour");

var dtoldDay = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oldTimeDay");
var dtoldMonth = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oldTimeMonth");
var dtoldYear = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oldTimeYear");

//- Pega todos os tempos da ultima vez que abriu



//- Calcula a diferença entre os segundos

var resultadoSeg = dtnow.Second - dtoldSec;


//- Calcula a diferença entre os segundos



//- Calcula a diferença entre os minutos e transforma para segundos

var resultadoMin = (dtnow.Minute - dtoldMin) * 60;

//- Calcula a diferença entre os minutos e transforma para segundos



//- Calcula a diferença entre as horas e transforma para segundos

var resultadoHora = (dtnow.Hour - dtoldHour) * 3600;

//- Calcula a diferença entre as horas e transforma para segundos



//- Calcula a diferença entre os dias e transforma para segundos

var resultadoDias = (dtnow.Day - dtoldDay)* 86400;

//- Calcula a diferença entre os dias e transforma para segundos



//- Calcula a diferença entre os meses e transforma para segundos

var resultadoMeses = (dtnow.Month - dtoldMonth)* 2592000;

//- Calcula a diferença entre os meses e transforma para segundos



//- Calcula a diferença entre os anos e transforma para segundos

var resultadoAno = (dtnow.Year - dtoldYear)* 31536000;

//- Calcula a diferença entre os anos e transforma para segundos






//- Calcula o resultado total

var resultadoTotal = resultadoSeg + resultadoMin + resultadoHora + resultadoDias + resultadoMeses + resultadoAno;


print ("resutado: " + resultadoTotal);

//- Calcula o resultado total



//--------------------------- Calculo das diferenças dos tempos --------------------------- 




//--------------------------- Calculo das Barras ---------------------------


var FomeBarra = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("FomeValor");

var FelicidadeBarra = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("FelicidadeValor");



BarraFome.value = FomeBarra - resultadoTotal;

BarraFelicidade.value = FelicidadeBarra - resultadoTotal;


PlayerPrefs.Save();
//--------------------------- Calculo das Barras ---------------------------



}

function Update()
{


}

function CurrentTime() { 

var dt : System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now;

var d : int = dt.Day;

var mo : int = dt.Month;

var y : int = dt.Year;

var h : int = dt.Hour; 

var m : int = dt.Minute; 

var s : int = dt.Second;


}


function OnApplicationQuit() {



    var dt : System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now;




//-------------- Guarda o Valor das Barras --------------


    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("FomeValor", BarraFome.value);

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("FelicidadeValor", BarraFelicidade.value);


//-------------- Guarda o Valor das Barras --------------           



//-------------- Guarda o Valor dos Tempos --------------   

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oldTimeSecond", dt.Second);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oldTimeMinute", dt.Minute);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oldTimeHour", dt.Hour);


    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oldTimeDay", dt.Day);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oldTimeMonth", dt.Month);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("oldTimeYear", dt.Year);


    PlayerPrefs.Save();


//-------------- Guarda o Valor dos Tempos --------------


}
```

Comment: Você verificou como está o PlayerPref no dispositivo, para ver se de fato escreveu alguma coisa? - vai precisar de root para o diretório data.
Outra forma é verificar se está voltando alguma coisa com  PlayerPrefs.HasKey (key).
Achei estranho é usar .Save() toda hora. Isso é para um "checkpoint" ou coisa do tipo, o Unity faz isso automático para você quando o jogo fecha normalmente.
A propósito, o playerprefs é para usar em pequenas coisas, preferências do player, se você planeja usar ele como savegame vai começar a encontrar problemas conforme o tamanho dele aumenta.

Comment: Outra forma é usar a assinatura do método que retorna um valor padrão caso não encontre nada.

Comment: Obrigado! Mas resolvi trocando de OnApplicationQuit(), para OnApplicationPaused(). O jogo é pausado antes de fechar, então acho que faz sentido...